# _ is undefined in a webworker file

Tags: javascript, angularjs, web-worker

The _ refers to lodash which I have as a file included into the index.html. No other errors referring to lodash occur except when loading and using the file that the worker function calls.

`<script src="bower_components/lodash/lodash.js"></script>`

I am not sure where to start looking. This is the line where the error occurs : `var lodash = _;`

And it is initialized as such: `var worker = new Worker('myWorker.js');`

I am sure that the worker file is uploaded because it isn't included in the html at all.

Comment: Workers don't have access to the global variables of the window. You'll want to [import the external scripts](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Workers_API/Using_web_workers#Importing_scripts_and_libraries).

Comment: Thank you, I literally just found that. It solved my problem. Greatly appreciated.